# podman: Error: failed to parse "X-Registry-Auth" header

Tags: podman

I'm trying to use [podman](https://podman.io/) for the first time (under Mac OS with `podman machine`, but this is probably irrelevant). When I try to start busybox image as a test, [like described in Introduction](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/Introduction.html):

```sh
podman run -it docker.io/library/busybox
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: failed to parse "X-Registry-Auth" header for /v3.3.1/libpod/images/pull?alltags=false&arch=&authfile=&os=&password=&policy=missing&quiet=false&reference=docker.io%2Flibrary%2Fbusybox&username=&variant=: error storing credentials in temporary auth file (server: "https://index.docker.io/v1/", user: ""): key https://index.docker.io/v1/ contains http[s]:// prefix
```

(podman version 3.3.1)

Answer (score 11):

The reason was that I had `~/.docker/config.json` file created by Docker Desktop. It had empty entry for docker.io registry, without credentials, which was causing this error.

As this file had no valuable configuration (mostly default values), I deleted it and problem no longer occured.

```
% podman run -it docker.io/library/busybox
Trying to pull docker.io/library/busybox:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob sha256:8ec32b265e94aafb0d43ab71f1d8f786122c19afb37d25532aea169f414f8881
Copying blob sha256:8ec32b265e94aafb0d43ab71f1d8f786122c19afb37d25532aea169f414f8881
Copying config sha256:42b97d3c2ae95232263a04324aaf656dc80e7792dee6629a9eff276cdfb806c0
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
/ #
```

Comment: This solution worked. I had docker desktop (osx) first and could not make `podman pull` work while `podman login` worked flawless.

Comment: I also had to remove `~/.dockercfg`.

Answer (score 2):

Edit `~/.docker/config.json` file and remove `https://`

Config before (not working)

```json
{
{
  "credsStore" : "desktop",
  "auths" : {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/" : {

    },
    "xxx-yyy-docker.artifactory.zzzz.com" : {

    },
    "registry.gitlab.zzzz.com" : {

    }
  },
  "credHelpers" : {
    "gcr.io" : "gcloud",
    "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev" : "gcloud"
  }
}
```

After (working ok)

```json
{
{
  "credsStore" : "desktop",
  "auths" : {
    "index.docker.io/v1/" : {

    },
    "xxx-yyy-docker.artifactory.zzzz.com" : {

    },
    "registry.gitlab.zzzz.com" : {

    }
  },
  "credHelpers" : {
    "gcr.io" : "gcloud",
    "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev" : "gcloud"
  }
}
```

Comment: More info about this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credential-helpers and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/